# Unix , vim ,wrapping function ,

Tags: unix, vim, wrapper

I want to provide function wrapping functionality in 
Vim editor . similar to the wrapping functionality which 
Is there in Netbeans and other softwares .

```
Sub sample {
_----------------
-------------------
}
```

Output:

```
+sub sample {
```

After clicking the above thing it should show full data.
Can we do it by using JavaScript in `.vimrc` file? please 
With constructive ideas .

Comment: Open vim. Type `:help folding` and read the documentation about the feature that is already built into vim.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vim folding commands
---------------------------------
zf#j creates a fold from the cursor down # lines.
zf/ string creates a fold from the cursor to string .
zj moves the cursor to the next fold.
zk moves the cursor to the previous fold.
za toggle a fold at the cursor.
zo opens a fold at the cursor.
zO opens all folds at the cursor.
zc closes a fold under cursor. 
zm increases the foldlevel by one.
zM closes all open folds.
zr decreases the foldlevel by one.
zR decreases the foldlevel to zero -- all folds will be open.
zd deletes the fold at the cursor.
zE deletes all folds.
[z move to start of open fold.
]z move to end of open fold.
```

So if you wanted to fold a method, you would position your cursor on the method declaration and type `zf}`. This will fold every line between your cursor and the method's closing brace. To unfold you would type `zo` with your cursor on the fold.